# sata hdd recognizing problem

Tags: 18.04, server, hard-drive, sata

Here is the simple lshw result

```
efirlus@Efirlus-NAS:~$ sudo lshw -c storage -c disk
  *-storage
       description: SATA controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 
  *-storage
       description: SATA controller
       product: JMicron Technology Corp.
       vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
       physical id: 0
       capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       logical name: scsi0
       capabilities: emulated
     *-disk
          description: ATA Disk
          product: ADATA SU800NS38
          logical name: /dev/sda
          size: 119GiB (128GB)
```

and dmesg result

```
efirlus@Efirlus-NAS:~$ dmesg | grep -i ata
[    4.679879] ahci 0000:00:12.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    4.701452] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xa131d000 port 0xa131d100 irq 125
[    4.701859] ahci 0000:01:00.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 5 ports 6 Gbps 0x1f impl SATA mode
[    4.709749] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xa1210000 port 0xa1210100 irq 127
[    4.709755] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xa1210000 port 0xa1210180 irq 128
[    4.709760] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xa1210000 port 0xa1210200 irq 129
[    4.709765] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xa1210000 port 0xa1210280 irq 130
[    4.709769] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xa1210000 port 0xa1210300 irq 131
[    5.022784] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    5.176281] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.177324] ata1.00: ATA-10: ADATA SU800NS38, Q0518BS, max UDMA/133
[    5.177335] ata1.00: 250069680 sectors, multi 2: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    5.178223] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    5.178668] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ADATA SU800NS38  8BS  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    5.494392] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    5.806283] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    6.118090] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    6.431402] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    8.302686] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

I plugged 2 hard drives on sata controller but didn't recognize.

please help alot

---

here is the lsblk result

```
efirlus@Efirlus-NAS:~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
└─sda2         8:2    0 118.8G  0 part /
mmcblk0      179:0    0  14.7G  0 disk
└─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0  14.7G  0 part /boot/efi
mmcblk0boot0 179:8    0     4M  1 disk
mmcblk0boot1 179:16   0     4M  1 disk
```

Comment: What is the `lsblk` output?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I added lsblk output.

Comment: I see 4 `disk`s. Is it what you expect? The last 2 disks (each is only 4MB of size) do not have any partitions on them.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Not really, as you can expect, it's impossible to buy just 4mb hdd....

my hdd is 10tb wd.

Comment: The OS version and / or your computer's firmware may not support such large disks. Some more experienced users may help you. (BTW, do you see these disks recognized in your computer's BIOS screen?)